# Pull pod metrics to external prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks

I'm trying to aggregate all the metrics, EC2 (CPU, ram, disk) and Pods (CPU, ram, disk) from inside a EKS cluster using an existing Prometheus (external to the cluster). I started adding data using node-exporter, kube-state-metrics but I'm stuck at deploying metrics-server. Using helm I conf and installed it, `kube top` and `kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods" | jq` are pulling data, but can someone advise on how can I pull all this to my external Prometheus ? 
Is there a way to expose this to a /metrics URL?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to use prometheus federation. In that setup,

1. You'll have one in-cluster prometheus and your original external prometheus. The in-cluster prometheus does the actual collection and temporary storage.
2. In your external prometheus, you'll scrape the `/federate` endpoint of your in-cluster prometheus. The `/federate` is specifically designed for the use case you are trying

This is the best method for having performant and reliable scraping of metrics. Getting the metrics via apiserver would not be a good way. Even if it's possible, would put unnecessary strain on the apiserver.